# Is it right as cannabis addicts addressing themselves as shiv bhakts?

Tags: shiva, shaiva-siddhanta

In India everywhere I see people are addressing themselves as **shiv bhakts** smoking weed and chillum and all sorts of herbs. Even some of the guys are making songs over it and some even smoke cannabis saying that Lord shiva used to smoke it so it's not harmful. People are making songs over it. 
So coming to my question I would like to ask if it is right that Lord shiva is being an inspiration to the youths smoking weed? And how to enlighten them with sacred texts where we can show them the right path showing them the positive side and why it's harmful even if the Lord did it. 
Also can I get the reference to the veda where Lord shiva is addressed as such a guy and are there any contradictions to that? 
Thank you.

Comment: You are making a generalised statement about devotees of Shiva.  In every method,  there will be a segment of people,  who deviates from the mainstream into methods,  which should be considered as obnoxious.  Pure spiritual aspects and obnoxious methodso are different. @Sachin Bahukhandi

Comment: I agree on that. But it's not just a group of guys. People are making songs on it. And it's being openly promoted. I guess the mahakaal incarnation of Lord shiva potrayed him as such a guy but an answer to the shloka which promotes him as such a guy and to show those people that he did that for a cause would be beneficial. He even drank poison during the samudra manthana but no one dared doing it because it's lethal. I don't have a problem with someone expressing his views over Lord shiva. I have problem with people who are defaming Hinduism saying that the Lord's themselves were addicts.

Comment: Which sloka are you referring to?@Sachin Bahukhandi

Comment: Even in Devi pujas, some people are resorting to obnoxious methods in the name of Tantra.  It does not mean that entire system is wrong.  We should not generalise.@Sachin Bahukhandi

Comment: Well Shiva has never done weed and renounces all materialistic things so these people are NOT Shiva bhakts.

Comment: But you can see everywhere. Almost every song associated with mahadev is associated with weed and all the other illegal stuffs. Addicts smoke and call themselves bhakts of mahakaal! So can we enlighten them? This was my question. And if yes then how. About slokas I just wanted to know if there is any sloka or any verse which says that shiva smoked cannabis and all.

Comment: Why do you worry about the people around you,  who according to you,  are  going in a wrong way?  It is not your duty to rectify every wrong on the society.   You can go in right way and be happy. @Sachin Bahukhandi

Comment: Actually this was asked in a debate I attended. And because this is really a question of debate because at least hinduism gives us a freedom to question the belief and ideology.

Comment: This is not an objective question. "Is it right for XYZ to address themselves as ABC?" - this is asking for opinions of others. So will most likely be closed with the [same reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LC8n.png).

Comment: This is why I hate asking questions on SO. I mean really? XYZ as ABC? No, it's asking if XYZ is really ABC or not. If people can question him as the lord of death and we have a reason to support this clause, why don't we have something to support the clause that yes he did cannabis because of **some** particular reason.

Comment: In the question you are asking for opinion of others on a subjective issue: "So coming to my question I would like to ask if it is right that Lord Shiva is being an inspiration to the youths smoking weed?" How is one supposed to answer this? Like I said, this will lead to opinion-based answers like the one below.

Comment: Isn't there something like this: **And how to enlighten them with sacred texts where we can show them the right path showing them the positive side and why it's harmful even if the Lord did it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it right as cannabis addicts addressing themselves as shiv bhakts?

**Some of the sects of Shaivism have practices that are related to drug usage, sexuality, and death themes. So it is not unimaginable that people who do drugs and have an interest in religion will be attracted to these Tamasic sects.**

The medieval Vedanta scholar Yamunacharya in his work called *Agama Pramanya* talks about the different Shaiva sects that existed during his time:

> There are four kinds of followers of the way of life set forth in those [Shaiva] Tantras: the Kapalikas, Kalamukhas, Pashupatas, and Shaivas. The Kapalika doctrine is described as follows: ... "He who knows the identities of the six mudrikas and is expert in the supreme Mudra, and meditates upon the self **in the vulva posture**, attains nirvana." - page 69
>
> The same is true of the Kalamukhas who teach that certain practices, which are condemned by all the shastras, **like eating from a skull, bathing in and tasting of ashes of cremated corpses, ... putting up wine-cups and worshipping the deity in them**, will secure all material and immaterial desires: **these teachings are outside the Veda.** - page 69-70

So these practices are not right because they are non-Vedic.

People who do drugs, smoke cannabis, etc will find common ground with these Shaiva sects.

**However, Shiva himself doesn't actually support these practices.** He actually composed and revealed false scriptures under the order of Vishnu to delude people who have been cursed by the Rishis to acquire non-Vedic beliefs:

*Varaha Purana:*

> In the last yuga (Kali), peoplewho resort to me are very rare. I shall produce delusion which will confuse  the people. - 70.35
>
> “You, Rudra, of mighty arms, shall produce the (seemingly) instructive texts which cause delusion.  By just a little effort, produce a large result!” - 70.36

Comment: Thank you. I find an answer which can exactly point out to what I wanted to achieve and not like the others who were either putting up their ideologies or telling me to mind my own business.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi No problem. A lot of the people on this site are Shaivas and Shaktas, and so they would be kind of annoyed by questions like this.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi And also, Shiva himself doesn't advocate those practices.

Comment: I know. I am a firm believer of hinduism myself. Being a student but practice Hinduism as much as I can. But the media is potraying Lord shiva as someone who smokes weed and chillum yet as much as I know he did all this during his kaalbhairava avatar. Like your answer suggests.